# Cannot open tomcat with localhost:8080, even though it is started in eclipse, only for this workspace

Tags: localhost, tomcat7

I'm new to java. I Have imported a project through **svn**. And want deploy it using **tomcat**. After maven clean, build and install, copied the war file to webapps folder. Started tomcat. But when trying to load from browser, I get this :

> This localhost page can’t be found
>
> No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/

I have selected tomcat installation as server location and I have tried out all options discussed in stackoverflow.

When I use a different workspace, where I have deployed a different project, tomcat works fine there. But in this workspace, it shows this error.

Please help out.